# Do calculation by retrieving data from Child Node is not working at all in Android Studio/Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I have a problem to do subtract calculation by retrieving data from a Child Nod. As you can see my layout below, what I want to do is to ***get Remaining Kcal value by calculating Daily Kcal value minus Total Kcal and display the Remaining Kcal to the TextView***.

[image: layout]

I suspected the calculation for the subtraction part (code below) is not working at all as I tried to put the remainingCount/remainingCalorie value into firebase but nothing happened.

```java
 //CALCULATE AND DISPLAY REMAINING CALORIE
    private void updateRemainingKcal(final double finalCount) {

        DatabaseReference userRecord = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference userReference = userRecord.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                double remainingCount = 0;

                for (DataSnapshot userChild: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot recordSnapshot: userChild.getChildren()) {
                        double userCalorie = Double.valueOf(recordSnapshot.child("daily calorie").getValue(String.class));
                        remainingCount = userCalorie - finalCount;
                        userRemainingCalorie.setText((remainingCount  +"kcal"));

                        myHistoryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                                getReference("History").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .child(date_record).child("Total Calorie");

                        Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
                        values.put("remainingCalorie", remainingCount);

                        myHistoryRef.updateChildren(values).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                Log.d("TAG", remainingCount + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is relevant code to do this operation, whereby I need to retrieve "daily calorie' from User first, then I can do the substraction daily calorie (Required Kcal) - total calorie consume (Total Kcal) = Remaining Calorie (Remaining Kcal):

```java
        //**********************DATABASE REFERENCE FOR USER REQUIRED CALORIE***************************//
        requiredCalorieRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        requiredCalorieRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                String userCalorieSuggestion = String.valueOf((dataSnapshot.child("daily calorie").getValue()));
                userRequiredCalorie.setText((userCalorieSuggestion  +"kcal"));


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

    //CALCULATE AND DISPLAY TOTAL CALORIE ACCORDING TO DATE
    private void updateTotalCalorie(final String date_n) {

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference nameRef = rootRef.child("UsersRecords").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(date_record);
        nameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                double count = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot foodTypeSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot recordSnapshot: foodTypeSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        double foodCalorie = Double.valueOf(recordSnapshot.child("foodCalorie").getValue(String.class));
                        count = count + foodCalorie;
                        userTotalCalorie.setText((count  +"kcal"));


                        myHistoryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                                getReference("History").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .child(date_record).child("Total Calorie");

                        Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
                        values.put("totalCalorie", count);
                        values.put("Date Consume", date_n);

                        final double finalCount = count;
                        myHistoryRef.updateChildren(values).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                updateRemainingKcal(finalCount);
                            }
                        });


                    }
                }
                Log.d("TAG", count + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });



    }

    //CALCULATE AND DISPLAY REMAINING CALORIE
    private void updateRemainingKcal(final double finalCount) {

        DatabaseReference userRecord = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference userReference = userRecord.child("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                double remainingCount = 0;

                for (DataSnapshot userChild: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot recordSnapshot: userChild.getChildren()) {
                        double userCalorie = Double.valueOf(recordSnapshot.child("daily calorie").getValue(String.class));
                        remainingCount = userCalorie - finalCount;
                        userRemainingCalorie.setText((remainingCount  +"kcal"));

                        myHistoryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                                getReference("History").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .child(date_record).child("Total Calorie");

                        Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
                        values.put("remainingCalorie", remainingCount);

                        myHistoryRef.updateChildren(values).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                Log.d("TAG", remainingCount + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my firebase looks like - there is no node of RemainingCalorie at all at History node:
[image: firebase]

How **can I solve this issue** despite knowing the problem. I have tried several ways but nothing could help to solve this code problem.

Comment: So 2354 - 529? And you want to display the value?. Sorry I didn't get your point.

Comment: yes @Ticherhaz, but to do that I need to retrieve user Daily Calorie first from Database Reference.

Comment: Can you remove all the code that are not relevant to the questions, quite confusing for me to understand.

Comment: @Ticherhaz : This is my entire firebase looks like https://i.imgur.com/OMgPOdu.png. Wait I will remove all code that are not relevant

Comment: @Ticherhaz : I have edited and only write the relevant codes only

Comment: Have you tried get the value from the user (daily calorie) , and then, get the value from totalCalorie, finally subtract them.

Comment: @Ticherhaz : yes I have tried it, but nothing work. the daily calorie is not even retrieved even I use the database reference method

Comment: @Ticherhaz : I tried to retrieve the daily calorie but it gives me java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null while it is not NULL

Comment: @Ticherhaz : Hi, it's okay. I have answered my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own problem. Thank you, finally did it. This is right code for those who have same problem in future:

```
private void updateRemaining(final int finalCount) {
    userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    userDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String user = String.valueOf((dataSnapshot.child("daily calorie").getValue()));
            int dailyCalorie = Integer.parseInt(user);
            int remainingCalorie = dailyCalorie-finalCount;
            userRemainingCalorie.setText((remainingCalorie  +"kcal"));

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }

    });
}
```

this is the screen-shot
[image]